# The effect of a change of variables on a CDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

The change of variable formula, tells us how applying a function on random variables affects the joint PDF of distribution of those variables. Unfortunately it does not immediately tell us how it affects the joint CDF  (cumulative distribution function) of them. I am wondering about that.

In summary the question is: **how applying a function affects the joint CDF of the random variables?**

Giving hints on how to derive or referring me to relevant references would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An infinitesimal probability $f(x)d^nx$ for $n$-dimensional $x$ can be rewritten if $y=g(x)$ using the chain rule $d^ny=|J|d^nx$, where $J$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix defined by $J_{ij}:=\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}$. So $f(x)d^nx=\frac{f(g^{-1}(y))}{|J|}d^ny$. For arbitrary $g$, simultaneous conditions of the form $Y_i\le y_i$ are not in general expressible as simultaneous conditions of the form $X_i\le x_i$; this complicates a comparison in terms of CDFs.

Comment: Hmm, are you considering one dimensional random variables $X$ to simplify? Otherwise the inequality is not defined. Also, I see the constraints proposed on the function, but do not see a major hint beyond that. Could you elaborate more please? I also see the hint that PDF is a derivative of a CDF, but still I am not sure why the effect on the CDF more" fundamental" than the effect on a PDF? What does it mean to be more "fundamental"?

Comment: @user25004 Sorry, my answer was most helpful for the univariate case. I've amended it to discuss the multivariate case, PDFs first.